# Aggregation and Sum with one Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view where I get some values and diffs from my database. I use this code:

```
Select DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, t1.HorasEfe)) as Soma, t1.IDDiligencia
from DiligenciaSub t1
group by t1.IDDiligencia,t1.HorasEfe
order by t1.HorasEfe
```

I get this as output:

[image]

What I need:

Sum the values from Soma where IDDiligencia is equal!

Is it possible to adapt my actual query to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take `HorasEfe` out of the grouping and add `SUM`:

```
Select SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, t1.HorasEfe))) as Soma, t1.IDDiligencia
from DiligenciaSub t1
group by t1.IDDiligencia
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, t1.HorasEfe)) as Soma, t1.IDDiligencia
from DiligenciaSub t1
group by t1.IDDiligencia
order by DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, t1.HorasEfe))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
SUM(Select (DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(day, 0, t1.HorasEfe))) from DiligenciaSub t1) as Soma,
t1.IDDiligencia
from DiligenciaSub t1
group by t1.IDDiligencia,t1.HorasEfe
order by t1.HorasEfe
```

Answer (score 0):

remove sum and group by from your original query then

insert your result into temp table #t

and then use this query

```
select sum(soma) as sum_soma,IDDiligencia as idd
from #t
group by IDDiligencia
```

you will get the following result

[image]